# Laravel Get Mail className from MessageSending event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.7, when sending an email using the Mail interface two events fired `Mail\Events\MessageSending` and `Mail\Events\MessageSent`, so my goal is to catch the MessageSending event and get the mailable class used to send the email (example `mail\Ordershipped`) and stop it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogSendingMessage
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  MessageSending  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {

        //here i want to check what mailable class used and stop it.
        if ($mailable == 'Ordershipped')
        return false;

        // if another mailable class (example: userVerification)
        else
        
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: have to tried get class on $event get_class

Comment: @JagadeshaNH - this return `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` fired event class, I'm trying to get the mailable class, but, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this point in time the Event does not know what the mailable type is since the HTML has already been built from the blade.

However you can append values to the underlying swift mail class in your mailable.

In your `App\Mail` folder create a file called `Mailable.php`. This is now your new mailable class that all your mailables will extend off of.

```
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as MailerContract;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable as BaseMailable; // Extend off laravel mailable

abstract class Mailable extends BaseMailable
{
    public function send(MailerContract $mailer)
    {
        //Initializes properties on the Swift Message object
        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $message->mailable = get_class($this);
        });

        parent::send($mailer);
    }
}
```

Use this class for all of your mailables like so:

```
use App\Mail\Mailable; // This is your new mailable parent class

class UserConfirmEmail extends Mailable
{
    public function build()
    {
         // Build email
    }
}
```

You can then get the mailable name from your swift_mail object which is the message attribute off of the `$event` variable e.g. `$event->message`.

```
// App\Listeners\LogMessageSending.php
public function handle(MessageSending $event)
{

    //here i want to check what mailable class used and stop it.
    if ($event->message->mailable == 'Ordershipped') {
        return false;
    }
    // if another mailable class (example: userVerification)
    else {
     return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds great, can you tell me steps how and where can I "create a mailable class that extends off the laravel mailable"??

Comment: Sure, The first code block is what your new mailable class will look like. I've added another code block showing what your mailables will look like.

Comment: thanks bro, it's working, I have only have one more question since I'm creating a laravel package, so I don't want the user to change the parent mailable class for each mailable, is there any workaround so I can extend it from my package without directly modify the mailable class.

Comment: @YassineQoraiche Hmm, for a package the most elegant solution I can think of is to overwrite the laravel command `php artisan make:mail` to use your mailable instead of the laravel one.  Then pretty much copy the laravel command code but put your mailable class instead of laravels one.

Comment: @yassineqoraiche. No elegant way that I'm aware of. I think users of your package will have to use the package mailable to extend off. I think thats fine as you are keeping it explicit. Perhaps you could make your own mail service provider but that is a bit of work.

Comment: in Laravel 9 it is `$this->withSymfonyMessage(...)` instead of  `$this->withSwiftMessage(...)`